# Chrome extension context menu ä ö encoding

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have an extension that's adding multiple context menu items where some of the titles include characters such as ä and ö. I'm developing on a macbook and on my local mac os the context menus are fine, however when I run my extension on windows computers, the characters are decoded incorrectly e.g. ä = Ã¤ and ö = Ã¶. I'm somewhat convinced this has something to do with ISO-8859-1 / Windows-1252 encoding, but if that's the case, I'm having trouble setting up the correct encoding in my background-file for the context menu items. I'm using pug-format as the template for my background.js and the problem persists even if I set the meta charset to ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.
Is there something silly that's going over my head?

Comment: Sounds like some or all of your files aren't saved in UTF-8 format.

Comment: .. duh. I was missing the meta charset for UTF-8 on my background.js even before I started messing around with ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. Oh do I feel like a jackass right now. Thank you for pointing it out